# Ruby: Split / Sort array based on condition

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, split

I have an array of holidays:

```
Holiday.all                        
Holiday Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "holidays".* FROM "holidays"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Holiday id: 1, name: "Dia da Confraternização Universal", holidayable_id: 1, holidayable_type: "Country", date: "2014-01-01", created_at: "2014-11-05 21:38:13", updated_at: "2014-11-05 21:38:13", verified?: false>, #<Holiday id: 2, name: "Natal", holidayable_id: 1, holidayable_type: "Country", date: "2014-12-25", created_at: "2014-11-05 22:02:33", updated_at: "2014-11-05 22:02:33", verified?: false>]>
```

I'd like to split this big array of dates by it's dates months, so I'd end up with 12 arrays (one for each month).

Comment: Could you post actual Ruby code?

Comment: Please all give an example of the array, with as few elements as needed for the question, and the desired output.

Comment: If you are retrieving these from a database, why not simply iterate over the months and pull them by month?

Comment: Sorry about posting pseudocode instead of actual code before. I thought it would be more useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use is the [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method.

> Groups the collection by result of the block. Returns a hash where the keys are the evaluated result from the block and the values are arrays of elements in the collection that correspond to the key.
>
> If no block is given an enumerator is returned.
>
> ```
> (1..6).group_by { |i| i%3 }   #=> {0=>[3, 6], 1=>[1, 4], 2=>[2, 5]}
> ```

For instance

```
["12/25", "01/01", (...)].group_by { |date| date.split("/").first }
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Strangely, the "ruby/array" api page doesn't mention "group_by".

Comment: That's because it's here: [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). If you're not familiar with the class `Enumerable`, have a browse. Those methods can be used with all types of collections (e.g., arrays, hashes, ranges, sets and others).